# Exporting one list into another

Tags: python, list, indexing, python-2.7

So I want to export the data from one list into another so I can mess with it and still have an untouched copy of the original data. I know you can do this with list splicing but I have to export the data from the first list only after an index value of i that is determined by a function previously defined. How would I choose that data only after i? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slice using `i`.

```
newlist = oldlist[i:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Splicing works. If x is your list, and f is your function, then

```
newlist = x[f():]
```

is your new list